# call awakeFromNib from another controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have class `TableViewCell1: UITableViewCell` with the following code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

            if (gender[0] == true){
                let origImage = UIImage(named: "maleP");
                let tintedImage = origImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
                genderButton[0].setImage(tintedImage, forState: .Normal)
                genderButton[0].tintColor = UIColor(hex: "d8006c")
            }
            else{
                let origImage = UIImage(named: "maleP");
                let tintedImage = origImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
                genderButton[0].setImage(tintedImage, forState: .Normal)
                genderButton[0].tintColor = UIColor(hex: "333333")

        }
        if (gender[1] == true){
            let origImage = UIImage(named: "femaleP");
            let tintedImage = origImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
            genderButton[1].setImage(tintedImage, forState: .Normal)
            genderButton[1].tintColor = UIColor(hex: "d8006c")
        }
        else{
            let origImage = UIImage(named: "femaleP");
            let tintedImage = origImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
            genderButton[1].setImage(tintedImage, forState: .Normal)
            genderButton[1].tintColor = UIColor(hex: "333333")

        }
    }
```

and I got left view controller, which have tableview controller, the problem is that I want clear the value inside the cell, to back what was before like reload it ..

```
 @IBAction func clearSelection(sender: AnyObject) {
         staticlink = ""
         attribute1 = [String]()
         values1 = [String]()

         gender = [false,false]
         seasons = [false,false,false,false]

        clickedsection = 10

         cliedkarry = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]

      tableView.reloadData()    
}
```

how I can apply my inaction to the tableview cell or all the tableview !?

I tried tableView.reloadData() but it didn't work, I guess because I register nibs in this way

```
tableData = [
    ["title": "Gender", "height": "120", "cellID": "cell1"]]

tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell1", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
```

this is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let record = tableData[indexPath.section];
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(record["cellID"] as! String)!
    cell.hidden = !(CBool(expandSections[indexPath.section] as! NSNumber))
    return cell
}
```

so how I can reload the data inside tableview cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want clear the value inside the cell, to back what was before like reload it

Okay you have that chance inside [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) method. It's called each time the cell will be re-cycled.

However what seems wrong with your code is that you are making some checks that obviously need to stay in the controller instead of cell's `awakeFromNib`. Simply use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and provide data to the cell and update it's UI over there. `awakeFromNib` will be called only once.

Comment: how i can do that :(

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. It'll be good to read this also: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you register nibs so tableView can reuse the cells which leads to "awakeFromNib" is not always called.You should update UI stuff elsewhere. And you should never call "awakeFromNib" manually. 
In your tableViewCell

```
func updateUI() {
    //do the UI stuff
}
```

In your controller

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let record = tableData[indexPath.section];
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(record["cellID"] as! String)!
    cell.hidden = !(CBool(expandSections[indexPath.section] as! NSNumber))
    if(!cell.hidden) cell.updateUI()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'updateUI'